# GUI and PSRemoting in Powershell CLI

Tags: winforms, powershell, gridview

Recently, I created a script that utilizes GUI's such as Out-GridView and Winforms and puts that module on a remote Windows 2012 server. This was to allow users to establish remote PSSessions and execute scripts from a centralized location.

**For Example:**

**1.** When attempting to call a winform I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "ShowDialog" with "0" argument(s): "Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style
to display a notification from a service application."
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
    + PSComputerName        : servera
```

**2.** 
When attempting to place results into an Out-GridView I get the following error:

```
Out-GridView does not work in a remote session.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...GridViewCommand:OutGridViewCommand) [Out-GridView], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemotingNotSupported,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutGridViewCommand
    + PSComputerName        : servera
```

**Question:**

Are there any workarounds that would allow me to utilize OGV and Winforms?

**Side note:**
 I am open to allowing the user to export the module to their physical workstation to let them use these options if need be - OGV and Winforms - only if there is an effective/secure means to do it.On the other hand, I am open to different suggestions.

Comment: 1. Get the data you need with remote session. 2. Use it in a form. 3. Profit?

Comment: Hello, I think you mean to declare a variable in the outer scope to reuse, if I am not mistaken. However, can you elaborate more on your solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the UI on your local machine, not the remote one.  Retrieve data remotely, display locally.

For instance:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer -Scriptblock { Get-Process } | Out-Gridview`

Using the gridview inside the scriptblock will attempt to launch the UI on RemoteServer and give you the error you mentioned.

Comment: This is definitely a viable solution. I have attempted it, are there any easier ways to go about doing this?

Comment: If you sign your modules and have them in a central location: your clients can import-module from their desktops and run them there, assuming their execution policy is at least as unrestricted as `RemoteSigned`.  There is no way I'm aware of to invoke a UI on the caller's machine from within a remote pssession.

Comment: For some reason I am unable to use Invoke-Command with my custom modules.... Is there a specific way to have the modules setup to use Invoke-Command?

Comment: We're starting to veer into another set of questions here.  The idea is to put your scripts (or modules) on a remote share.  From your desktop, you run the scripts/cmdlets - they would take arguments or be pre-coded which remote machines to target. You still have to follow the same basic principle of running code locally on your display machine, while retrieving data from remote machines using mechanisms like `invoke-command` or sessions.  `Invoke-Command` executes code at a the specified location, and there is no way for something within the invoked command to display UI locally.

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-Command` I think would be better here because you are telling the remote computer what to do instead of asking to interact directly with the remote computer using `Enter-PSSession`or `New-PSSession`.